# DispatcherServlet and Controller (Tomcat status 500)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, javabeans

I try to create some controllers and I've got some problem with RequestMapping (I think it's that a problem). This is must be an Web App with Spring.

```
 package Controllers;
 
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
  public class WelcomeRestController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
  public String welcome(){
    return "{message:welcome}";
   }
}
```

I also try to write @RequestMapping("/rest"), because if I don't declare the method, I've got the default one that is GET.

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
 @EnableWebMvc
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"Controllers"})
  public class WebConfig {}






 import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

 public class AppInizializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

protected Class<String>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[0];
}


protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
}


protected FrameworkServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
    DispatcherServlet ds= new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
    ds.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    return ds;
}


protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
       }
 }
```

When I start my code, Catalina deploy my project but give me some warning about BeanCreationException at RequestMapping, so in browser I see an HTTP STATUS 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

```
 03-Aug-2021 17:12:01.926 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] 
 org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string 
 [4.0]. Default version will be used.
 03-Aug-2021 17:12:02.570 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] 
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs 
 yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of 
 JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during 
 scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
 03-Aug-2021 17:12:02.625 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] 
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Initializing 
 Servlet 'dispatcher'
 03-Aug-2021 17:12:03.063 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] 
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh Exception 
 encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
 name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in 
 org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: 
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(java.lang.String)'
 03-Aug-2021 17:12:03.066 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(java.lang.String)'
```

I add all dependencies into Maven

My Maven Dependecies

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>CreoDispatcherServlet</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CreoDispatcherServlet</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven- 
war-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.8.M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.9</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--é a false perch+ non userò xml ma le annotation-->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I solved the problem opened just a different ide. I wrote this project using IJ, but it's work in Eclipse.

Comment: _"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(java.lang.String)'"_: your Spring dependencies must come from different releases. All Spring libraries should use the same exact version. Can you add your Maven dependencies to the question?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz i just added my pom.xml

Comment: `spring-webmvc` is latest than your others spring libs

Comment: @PawełGłowacz I updated all spring dependencies to the versoin 5.3.9, but nothin is change. I add some other dependencies, I see some tutorial on Youtube,and now I've got 404 status- not found.

Comment: So you updated all to 5.3.9 and 500 error did not show up. Seems good because version 5.3.4 and class `LogDelegateFactory` does not have `getHiddenLog(String)` link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.4/javadoc-api/index.html?index-files/index-7.html Version 5.3.9 has that method. So now you need to figure out why you have 404. Seems not configured web context in your application ?

Comment: @PawełGłowacz I solved the problem. I don't know for which reason, but when I opened my project with Exlipse, it works with no problem. Afer I tried again to open it with IJ (used for create this project) and it's also work if you go into debug->Modify Run Configuration->webapp(select it)->apply